# Write to File in First line in end of Loop

Tags: vba

I have a simple questions, after reading from record set and writing ti file in end of loop I need to write in the first line (rowcount) code as below:

```
   sFileName = "C:\filename.csv"

RowCount = 0
Open sFileNameFor Output As #1
Do While Not rst.EOF
    'Print #1, rst!Name
    Print #1, rst.Fields(0).Value & "|" & rst.Fields(1) ... rst.Fields(n).Value
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
    '--header and rowcount
      Print #1, "Header Line" & RowCount
```

I am not finding out how to add header in the first line of file  "C:\filename.csv"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you not move to the end of the recordset first, back to the front (`rst.MoveLast` followed by `rst.MoveFirst`) and then get the `rst.RecordCount` - you can then add the header in first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code which does the job - add it just below the Loop command:

```
Dim sFileContents As String

Close #1
Open sFileNameFor For Binary As 1
sFileContents = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, 1, sFileContents
Put #1, 1, "Header Line " & RowCount & vbCrLf
Put #1, , sFileContents
Close #1
```

Source:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-write-into-text-file-at-first-and-last-line-with-excel-vba.4046562/

Comment: Hello Darren, above code works perfectly. It just create some special chars at begging of first line, any idea how to remove it ! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure - I tried opening my test file in Notepad, Notepad++ and Wordpad but didn't see any special characters on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no collection of every `Field.Name` in the recordset. Instead, you have to loop over the collection `Fields` and get each items `.Name`-property like so:

```
For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i
```

Generate a string out of that with, let's say, something like this:

```
Dim strHeader as String
strHeader = rst.Fields(0).Name
For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    strHeader = strHeader & "|" & rst.Fields(i).Name
Next i
```

Counting `i` is obviously a bit weird, bc, you know, `0-based` arrays in VBA.

Hope that helps.